# Mistake in Game of Thrones S03E10?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S03E10, when ser Davos frees Gendry at Dragonstone, the directions he gives him seem to not correspond with the [map](http://www.sermountaingoat.co.uk/map/):

> - Row for a full day and night and you'll reach Rook's Rest. You'll want to stop there. Don't. She'll find you.
> - Where should I go?
> - You must keep the coast on your left side until you reach King's Landing.

But this doesn't quite correspond with the map:

[image]

From this it seems like the shore should be on the right side. So is it a mistake or did I get it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Another option is that since this map is called "speculative", there might be a mistake in the map itself.

Comment: It's possible there's no mistake and the map is accurate. He would likely be facing opposite his direction of travel while rowing, so the coast would be on his left.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy wow, I didn't think about this!! Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMurphy well done sir, you win the internet today. You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 11):

People who row a boat do so **with their backs turned** to the direction of travel.

[image]

If Gendry rows towards King's Landing back-first, then the coast is indeed to his left.

Comment: @Matt: While Davos is a nautical man, Gendry _can't even swim_. So him dumbing down the conversation for laymen makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks @Flater. I just noticed that myself and delete my comment, while you typed your reaction to mine. Sorry. Here's my updated comment: Usually rowing directions are given for the coxswain who faces the rower and looks ahead towards the bow. This would even have been the case if the rower was the only person and there was no coxswain. However, since Gendry isn't experienced with nautical topics, Davos explained it in a way that is easy to understand.